# $(a, b)$ pairs with $\gcd(a, b) = 1$

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

The title is stating clearly what I want to achieve, however, here's more background:
I'm trying to solve [problem #71 in Project Euler](https://projecteuler.net/problem=71) and my question would be:
I'm not trying to count them as in [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/108483/number-of-pairs-a-b-with-gcda-b-1), I'm trying to get the actual (a, b) pairs instead! Is there a better (i.e. more efficient) approach than brute force?
Thanks.

Comment: prime factorization, and sieve of eratosthenes on the prime factors.

Comment: Look at the [Stern-Brocot tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stern%E2%80%93Brocot_tree) and [Farey sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farey_sequence) and their construction using [mediants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediant_(mathematics)). You don't need to generate all the fractions, but do a binary search along the tree for the fraction that they are looking for.

Comment: I believe it is against site policy to take questions from Project Euler.  The organizers of that site have [asked us](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1090/re-project-euler-questions/3313#3313) to refrain.

Comment: @lulu: By "site policy", do you mean the policy of PE or of math.SE? I don't know about PE, but I'm pretty sure it's not against math.SE policy. See [our contest problem policy](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16774), [the most upvoted answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/21384) to a more recent meta thread about PE questions, and, last but not least, the [tag:project-euler] tag, which could hardly have accumulated $156$ questions if it went against our policy :-)

Comment: @Stoufa On the other hand, that shouldn't be your concern. It is their problem if they see as unwanted, a feature of PE, and of this site, that of being online with fairly relaxed authentication and access methods, and therefore necessarily allowing some level of collaboration. In my view, those types of open contests promote mathematical and programming culture. What a better way, than having the ideas easily accessible.

Comment: @lulu I'm not trying to cheat! That's why I stated clearly that this is for a Project Euler question, I'm not asking you to solve the question for me either. What I'm looking for is the mathematical shortcut allowing me to avoid the brute force approach.

Comment: @Stoufa: lulu didn't accuse you of trying to cheat.

Comment: [Here](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/blue/SB_props.shtml), in particular in [this subpage](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/blue/encoding.shtml) tells you how to navigate the Stern-Brocot tree. Once you get to $3/7$, which path (sequence of Left and Right child choices) you can precompute, even by hand, then all you need to do is take a Left and then Right, Right, Righ child, ... until you get to height $d$.

Comment: @joriki  Perhaps I have it wrong.  Hasn't this issue come up a lot?   There's a dozen posts on Meta about Project Euler and it seemed to me that the consensus was against responding to such questions.  But, maybe I misinterpreted.

Comment: @Stoufa  I absolutely did not accuse you of cheating!  You asked a fair question and were $100\%$ clear about the source.  It was my sense that Project Euler preferred that other sites not get involved with solving their problems, though I might have that wrong.  In any case, each user is free to decide on their own wether to respond or not.

Comment: @lulu: We probably read a different subset of the dozen posts :-). I've been taking my guidance from the ones I linked to above, but if you know of ones that show a clearer consensus and/or are more recent, I'm ready to be convinced. Note, though, that the contest policy is tagged "faq" (which as far as I understand makes it something like a semi-official policy) and the answer I linked to, which argues against treating Project Euler questions separately, quotes that policy and has the most upvotes in its thread.

Comment: @joriki  In the morning, I'll read through the posts over there.  It's likely I was too hasty.

Comment: @joriki  I think you have the better case here.  I'll withdraw my original objection to the problem.

Comment: @lulu We are not politicians, we are scientists, mathematicians, and engineers! We don't need to have such void quarrels! And if there are laws to separate theory from practice, they will be useless!

What's prohibited is to provide the final answer! Which wasn't our case here! I didn't ask for the left neighbor of 3/7, I asked if there is a better way than the naive brute force solution which I've tried and seemed very slow!

Finally, thanks so much for everyone who took some time to write a comment 
DonThousand, flan, lulu, joriki

Answer (score 0):

Since you don’t want us to solve the question for you, all that’s to be said has already been said in the comments. You can use Farey sequences; in particular, look at the section on [Farey neighbours](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farey_sequence#Farey_neighbours) in the Wikipedia article, which should allow you to quickly find the left neighbour of $\frac37$.